# How to create List of dictionaries from two list

Tags: python, list, dictionary

```
x = ['a', 'b', 'c']
y= [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
```

I want to create a list of dictionaries so the x and y values would correspond like this:

```
output: [{'a':1, 'b':2, 'c':3}, {'a':4, 'b':5, 'c':6}, {'a':7, 'b':8, 'c':9}]
```

Comment: The quick-and-dirty one-liner is: `[{k:v for k, v in zip(x, yy)} for yy in y]`

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) to create a dictionary from two lists: `dict(zip(keys, values))`

```py
out = [dict(zip(x, l)) for l in y]
```

Comment: Good point for using the `dict(zip(a,b))` rather than `{k:v for k,v in zip(a,b)}`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with list comprehension and enumerate that will get the corresponding value from the x list on each y iteration: 
`print([{x[inx]: z for inx, z in enumerate(i)} for i in y])` 
Output
`[{'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}, {'a': 4, 'b': 5, 'c': 6}, {'a': 7, 'b': 8, 'c': 9}]`